# What does the asterisk (*) do in grep -nri "searchString" *?

Tags: command-line, grep

Normally while searching using grep, the command I was using was this:

```
grep -nri "String"
```

whereas most of my colleagues do this:

```
grep -nri "String" *
```

What does the latter do (the `*` part)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`grep` with the `-r` flag operates on all files in the specified directories recursively:

```
-r, --recursive
      Read all files  under  each  directory,  recursively,  following
      symbolic  links only if they are on the command line.  Note that
      if  no  file  operand  is  given,  grep  searches  the   working
      directory.  This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
```

By default, if no directories are given, then `grep` will process all files in the current directory.

In `grep -r ... *`, then, the shell expands `*` to all files and directories in the current directory (usually except those that begin with a `.`), and `grep` then works recursively on *them*.

So, if you had a directory that contained, for example:

```
.git/
.gitignore
foo/
foo/.foo2
foo/link2 -> /foo2/bar2
bar
link1 -> /foo/bar
```

where the names ending with `/` are directories, then `grep -r` would also process the `.gitignore` file and everything in `.git`, but `grep -r ... *` would exand to `grep -r ... foo bar`, and would end up excluding `.gitignore` and `.git` (but it would include `foo/.foo2`).

Also note the point about symbolic links - if one of the files in the expansion of `*` was a symlink, the symlink target would be processed if you used `*`. So with `*`, `/foo/bar` will be processed as the target of `link1`, but not `/foo2/bar2` as the target of `link2`.

The overall effect:

```
                                 w/o *           with *
.git/                              +                -
.gitignore                         +                -
foo/                               +                +
foo/.foo2                          +                +
foo/link2 -> /foo2/bar2            -                -
bar                                +                +
link1 -> /foo/bar                  -                +
```

---

Which you want to do, of course, depends on whether you want those files and directories included in the search; but I tend to prefer having `grep` itself do the excluding and including using the `--exclude`/`--include` and other options.

Comment: Ninja'd. Just what I wanted to say as well...