# Why doesn't grep -r also look in subdirectories when I search with a glob?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

Grep with `-r` was not working for me.

I then made a test situation.  The directory `/home/den/backup` now contains a file with the word `washer` in it.  I also made a subdirectory within `/home/den/backup`.  In that directory a file contains the word `washer`.  The following should return two hits at  `/home/den/backup/great.txt` and `/home/den/backup/aaa/info.txt`

If I issue

```
grep -r "washer" /home/den/backup/*.*
```

the result is one hit.

If I issue

```
grep -r "washer" /home/den/backup/aaa/*.*
```

the result is one hit.

Shouldn't the first one have also found the second one, which is in one if its sub-directories?

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1028732/158442

Comment: `*.*` looks Windows-style. I prefer `find . -type f -name '*' -exec grep 'washer' \{\} \+` because `grep -r` is prone not to do what you want: Either it does not recurse (because directories are usually not named like `*.txt`) or it throws errors because directories not being regular files.

Comment: @Zanna with the updated title, looks more like a dupe of the post I linked to.

Comment: @muru so it does :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can see what's happening here by setting the shell into debug mode using `set -x`

```
$ set -x
$ grep -r "washer" /home/steeldriver/backup/*.*
+ grep --color=auto -r washer /home/steeldriver/backup/great.txt
washer
```

i.e. the shell is expanding `*.*` and matching the single file `great.txt` - so `grep` searches that single file.

If you want to recursively search the whole *directory*, just give the directory as the argument:

```
$ grep -r "washer" /home/steeldriver/backup/
+ grep --color=auto -r washer /home/steeldriver/backup/
/home/steeldriver/backup/aaa/info.txt:washer
/home/steeldriver/backup/great.txt:washer
```

(You can turn debug mode off again using `set +x`)